# Moving from Oracle 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.3

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, upgrade

We are going to upgrade our database soon from Oracle 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.3 We have our customer relation application that runs on the Oracle background. Both Oracle and the company that designed the application recommend an out of place upgrade and states that this means Oracle home should be different. My question is can we use the same instance name since we have several interfaces that work with this applications that use the "instance name" and I do not want anything else to break? I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 2):

The nice clean solution is to:

- install Oracle 11.2.0.3 on a new machine with the same machine name
- depending on your network putting the new one a different sub-net or in a fire walled zone could prevent network issues
- create an instance with the same name
- set the parameters and table spaces to be the same as the original
- import the data
- test, test, test again
- turn the old machine off
- join the new machine to the appropriate subnet/fire wall zone/domain

There are a number of other ways to do this including renaming the database using [DBNEWID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch14.htm) but a new install on a new machine is easy and allows you to increase memory and storage at the same time.

Note:  11.2.0.3 is already out of support, why not go to 11.2.0.4 which is supported for a little while longer?